# How to do this coordinate system operation more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, math, optimization, 2d, three.js

I'm making a 3D game, where the player's back should always be facing the camera and he should move in that direction. I didn't come to the "back facing the camera" part yet, but I believe that it will be simple once I figure out how to move the player in the right direction...

Though it is a 3D coordinate system, height can be ignored (z-axis) because no matter how high the camera is, the player should always be going in the same speed (the camera system is planned to function much like in the game World of Warcraft).

Now, I have summarized my problem to this...

- Point (0, 0) is the players position.
- Point (x, y) is the camera's position.
- The camera is (dx, dy) units away from the player (and because player is at (0, 0), it is also (x, y) units away, although this is a position vector, not a translation one)

Problem: how do I get a point (a, b) in this 2D space that lies on a circle r = 1 but is on the same line as (0, 0) and (x, y)?

Visualization:

[image]

By doing this, I should have a 2D vector (a, b), which would, when multiplied by -30, act as the speed for the player.

I know how to do this, but in a very expensive and inefficient way, using the Pythagora's theorem, square roots, and all those out-of-the-question tools (working in Javascript).

Basically, something like this:

```
c = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); //Get the length of the line
rat = 1/c; //How many times is the desired length (1) bigger than the actual length

a = x*rat;
b = y*rat;
```

There must be something better!

For reference, I'm making the game in Javascript, using the Three.js engine.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what you have to do.  How often do you need to calculate this?  If it's only at the frame rate, it doesn't sound like a very big deal...

Comment: Every time the mouse is moved, I guess. There's no other way? Bummer.

Comment: That's "expensive"? What kind of method are you hoping for?

Comment: Well, there *are* other ways (e.g. using `cos` and `sin`), but they probably won't be any more efficient.

Comment: You could add some memoization to the function so that you cache the result of the function+parameters if it is a pure function! http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/

Comment: @WillVousden I was hoping for something where I didn't really need to use square roots at all, I heard that I should always avoid them because they're hard to calculate.

Comment: @Shay: I can't imagine that would be beneficial here.

Comment: @Bane The alternative involves trigonometric functions, which are even slower. Try to avoid function calls as much as possible if you want to gain some speed. Maybe there's something better that can be done, but how much precision do you need?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Why not? If I execute f(2,3); 10 times I only pay the price of doing it once with memoization.  I must be missing something there!

Comment: @Shay I think memoizing all that is a bit overkill and may use a lot of memory. Maybe Bane can do something storing some square roots.

Comment: @MaxArt : Fair enough guys, the thing is, its really simple to test out though!

Comment: @Shay Well instead of some trivial CPU operations you suddenly have to access memory. That evicts other useful things out of the cache and means in the worst case we have to wait for a whole memory access (good bye several hundred CPU cycles). On the other hand 4 multiplications, 1 division, 1 add and 1sqrt with SSE takes worst case (single scalar operation latency) 4*5+14+14+3=51 cycles aka less than a single memory access to L3 cache. Obviously that's assuming a sensible compiler and JS performance is notoriously bad, so who knows. But in C, memoization would be a really bad idea.

Comment: @Voo: thanks for the rational explanation, tiny operations here that have no need for optimization. I was not looking at the triviality of the equation correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to make more efficient here, these calculations are standard stuff for 3D scenes.

Don't optimize prematurely. There is no way this stuff is a bottleneck in your app.

Remember, even if these calculations happen on each `render()`, they still only happen once every several milliseconds - 17ms assuming 60 FPS, which is *a lot*. `Math.sin()` / `Math.cos()` / `Math.sqrt()` are plenty efficient, and lots of other calculations happen on each `render()` that are *much* more complex.

You'll be just fine with what you have now.