# How do I calculate the rotation along the y-axis given a 2D direction vector?

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, rotation, three.js

I'm making a 3D game, and I need the player mesh always facing the back of the camera. I already figured out how to get a 2D speed vector (direction along the x-z plane), but now I need to rotate the mesh in the speed vector's direction...

Basically, every mesh has a `.rotation` property, and that property is a 3D vector. I am only interested in rotation over the y-axis, that's the one that is perpendicular to the surface (x-z) plane.

The rotation doesn't use degrees, but radians, so I thought it would be something like this:

`mesh.rotation.y = (mesh.direction.x - mesh.direction.z)*Math.PI*2;`

But this doesn't seem to cut it...

The direction/speed is a, as a said, 2D vector, and it consist of real numbers between -1 and 1. At all times `sqrt(x*x + y*y) == 1`, so it forms a "circle", this is because speed needs to be equal in all directions, obviously.

The speed vector changes only when I drag the mouse over the screen, and so should the rotation, and it is calculated like this:

```
var c = Math.sqrt(cameraPos.x*cameraPos.x + cameraPos.z*cameraPos.z); //This is the distance from the camera to the mesh, which is at (0, 0) for simplicity of this presentation.
var rat = 1/c;

mesh.direction.x = cameraPos.x*rat; //Direction vector = the speed vector
mesh.direction.z = cameraPos.z*rat;
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773693/how-to-do-this-coordinate-system-operation-more-efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [`atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) will do the trick:

```
mesh.rotation.y = Math.atan2(mesh.direction.z, mesh.direction.x)
```

Result is in radians. It basically calculates the angle between the vector and X axis. You might need to switch parameters or use minus operator here or there.